Timed Out waiting for nipyapi _schedule_controller_state to complete
I just updated NIFI from version 1.11.4 to 1.16.3. I got one issue. Once my nifi's registry flow is taken and shown on workspace and when it comes to start installation of componenets i got error on that line below. Note that all is working on older nifi version. What might be the issue?
self.__nipyapi.canvas.schedule_controller(i, False)

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deploy01.py", line 134, in <module>
    main_handler.start_controllers()
  File "/code/nifi.py", line 1441, in start_controllers
    self.__start_controller_safe()
  File "/code/nifi.py", line 710, in __start_controller_safe
    self.__nipyapi.canvas.schedule_controller(i, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nipyapi/canvas.py", line 1249, in schedule_controller
    state_test = nipyapi.utils.wait_to_complete(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nipyapi/utils.py", line 243, in wait_to_complete
    raise ValueError("Timed Out waiting for {0} to complete".format(
ValueError: Timed Out waiting for _schedule_controller_state to complete
make: *** [Makefile:193: nifi-flow-deployment] Error 1

Code:
def __start_controller_safely(self) -> bool:
    for i in (
            self.__nipyapi.nifi.FlowApi()
        .get_controller_services_from_group(self.deployed_flow_id)
        .controller_services
    ):

        _ctrl_id = i.id
        print(i.component.name)
        if i.status.run_status == "DISABLED":
            print("Controller status is disabled... trying to start")
            self.__nipyapi.canvas.schedule_controller(i, True)
            while (
                    self.__nipyapi.canvas.get_controller(
                        _ctrl_id, identifier_type="id"
                    ).status.run_status
                    != "ENABLED"
            ):
                if (
                        self.__nipyapi.canvas.get_controller(
                            _ctrl_id, identifier_type="id"
                        ).status.run_status
                        != "ENABLED"
                ):
                    print("Controller status is enabled")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Waiting controller to start")
                    time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print("Controller already started")

    self.are_controllers_started: bool = True
    return True

